# Access, Update Query that does not overwrite data with blank cells

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

With this Update Query, how can I prevent it from overwriting data in existing rows with blank cells?

```
UPDATE tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.thing0 = tbl2.thing0 
SET tbl2.[thing1] = tbl1.[thing1], tbl2.[thing2] = tbl1.[thing2], tbl2.[thing3] = tbl1.[thing3];
```

I have users on-site updating a table in real time and worry that remote users updating the table once they have a connection will overwrite the on-site users data with a bunch of blank cells.

Will something like this work if I add it to the end?

```
WHERE Not Null;
```

Edit1 for Hansup

Empty in this case means on row1 of the tbl1 where, Onsite User entered data in columns 2 through 7(things redacted in code above). Offsite user has entered nothing in this row today. Offsite user uses the query above to update tbl1. Since columns 2 through 7 are empty on his table, I don't want his work to overwrite Onsite User's edits with blank cells.

Edit2 For HanSup and luk2302

Each row is a project. The projects are created by one user, then multiple users update the projects over their life. So Picture Row 1, thing1, as a customer name that has already been entered. Now, onsite user makes some updates. Offsite user makes none to this row, but then runs the update query.

Offsite user's update should only add info to existing rows, but not remove any data. If it overwrites data with data, I'm fine with that. We are just recording contact info and when certain milestones are reached. So long as the data gets there. I'm not worried about who inputs it.

Comment: no, that single statement at the end will only produce an error. What is "empty"? A row that has a matching thing0 but empty thing1, thing2 or thing3?

Comment: Empty in this case means on row1 of the tbl1 where, Onsite User entered data in columns 2 through 7(things redacted in code above). Offsite user has entered nothing in this row today. Offsite user uses the query above to update tbl1. Since columns 2 through 7 are empty on his table, I don't want his work to overwrite Onsite User's edits with blank cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse formatting, I'm answering from my phone...

You could replace the elements of the SET such that, for example:

SET tbl2.[thing1] = Iif(tbl1.[thing1] is null, tbl2.[thing1], tbl1.[thing2])

In that way, if your new value is null then the other value will be used.

Be aware of possible different behavior of null and empty string, depending on your use case... But you can change the condition to check for empty string too.